# difference between MultiSourceEditor and MultiPageEditorPart

Tags: eclipse, plugins, editor

I found the source code for the Plugin Manifest Editor, from Eclipse, and noticed that it uses another class as model. The MultiSourceEditor.

In my editor I´m using MultiPageEditorPart. And I need to open 2 source files here with it.

Basically, what are the differences between them? Maybe I should switch to this one?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.editor.MultiSourceEditor` is an **internal** editor used by the Plugin Development Environment. It extends `FormEditor` which itself is based on `MultiPageEditorPart`. The editor is just a specialized multi-page editor for PDE.

You must not use any **internal** classes, they are subject to change without notice - [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). You can, of course, look at the source code to see what it does.